# Is there any problem to stop/pause Spotify with google assistant on Nougat?

Tags: android, android-source, assistant

Google assistant commands "pause", "stop", "next", etc are not working anymore on my Android nougat devices but still working on my smartphone running Android pie.

I've tried different devices :

- Nexus 9 running stock android 7.1.1
- Nexus 9 running LineageOS 14.1
- Odroid XU4 running LineageOS 14.1

On each devices I've the same result, i'm able to start playing music on Spotify with the Google assistant but I can't pause/stop/next/prev.

If I ask "Ok google, stop", "Ok google, pause" or "Ok google, next", the Assistant tell me that he "can't help with that".

If I ask "Ok google, stop Spotify", he tell me that he must know "which device to use" and same result if I add "on this device", "on my phone", "on my tablet".

Actually :
Google apps and play services are up to date, I've wiped cache of all apps, make factory reset of my Nexus 9, re-flash stock images but still have the same issue.
And Spotify is well set as my default music service in the Google app.

Can you tell me please if you have the same issue or if you have any advices to fix it ?

Thank you,
Best regards.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is for **programming related questions only**. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su].

Comment: I experience the same problem on Pixel 4 with Android 10.